# Generating an email with an Excel XLSX attachment

Tags: perl, email-attachments, mime

The following Perl program gives an access denied error at line 44 when I try to print either the entire string or the encoded portion. If I print just the header using `$msg->print_header(\*STDOUT)`.

What I am trying to do is generate a text file that contains all the information that could be used in a telnet command to test a *Message Transfer Agent* (MTA) by sending an email with an attachment.

```
use MIME::Lite;
use Net::SMTP;

### Add the sender, recipient and your SMTP mailhost
my $from_address = 'temp999 at gmail.com';
my $to_address   = 'test05@gmail.com';
my $mail_host    = 'gmail.com';

### Adjust subject and body message
my $subject      = 'Testing script';
my $message_body = "I am sending an email with an attachment";

### Adjust the filenames
my $my_file_xlsx   = 'c:/temp';
my $your_file_xlsx = 'count.xlsx';

### Create the multipart container
$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    From    => $from_address,
    To      => $to_address,
    Subject => $subject,
    Type    => 'multipart/mixed'
) or die "Error creating multipart container: $!\n";

### Add the text for the message body
$msg->attach(
    Type => 'TEXT',
    Data => $message_body
) or die "Error adding the text message part: $!\n";

### Adding an Excel file
$msg->attach(
    Type        => 'application/octet-stream',
    Path        => $my_file_xlsx,
    Filename    => $your_file_xlsx,
    Disposition => 'attachment'
) or die "Error adding $file_xls: $!\n";

### Send the Message
MIME::Lite->send('smtp', $mail_host, Timeout => 60);
#$msg->send;
$msg->print(\*STDOUT); # Write to a file handle ### LINE 44 ###
#$msg->print_header(\*STDOUT); # Write the header
#$msg->print_body(\*STDOUT); # Write the encoded body
```

I haven't found anything matching exactly what I am trying to do, but I might not be using the correct terminology when searching.

Comment: i stated the incorrect line number producing the error. It should be line 44. Below is the exact error i am getting.                                                                                                                                                                                                           open c:/temp: Permission denied
 at send_attachment.pl line 44.

Comment: Please [*edit*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51470157/edit) your questions to correct any mistakes and to include additional information.

Comment: The correct MIME type for XLSX data is`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Comment: You *must always* add `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program you write.

Comment: It's depressing to still see people using older modules like MIME::Lite and Net::SMTP when better tools like [Email::Stuffer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer) exist.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to attach the file `c:/temp`, which is (presumably) a directory, not a file. When MIME::Lite tries to open it as a file to read the contents,it fails with that error. You probably meant to pass `c:/temp/count.xlsx` as `Path`.

Comment: I agree. The `Filename` field is just the name of the attachment and works as a hint for what name the recipient should use when saving the file (if/when the original filename is undesirable). `Path` should contain the actual name (and optionally path) of the file on the sender's computer.

Also, according to `MIME::Lite`'s documentation, its use is discouraged in favour of other libraries. Examples given include `Email::MIME`, `MIME::Entity` and `Email::Sender`.